# Regex to replace substring (if not the start of a word)

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm handling tweets like `@Alice @ home`. I want to convert user mentions to normal words (e.g. `@Alice => Alice`) *but keep* the individual `@` as a surrogate for `at`. So simply replacing all occurrences of `@` won't work.

I found out about the concept of word boundaries, but I haven't been able to make them work for this. For one,

```
print re.sub(r'\b@\b', '', '@Alice @ home')
```

doesn't change anything, while

```
print re.sub(r'\bAlice\b', '', '@Alice @ home')
```

results in `@ @ home`. So I assume that the at-sign (`@`) does not count as part of a word.

In short, I'm basically looking for the `pattern` so that

```
print re.sub(pattern, '', '@Alice @ home')
```

outputs `Alice @ home`.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may play with the boundaries `\B` and `\b`

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', r'', '@Alice @ home')
Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', r'', 'foo @Alice @ home')
foo Alice @ home
```

`\B` matches between two word characters or between two non-word characters. So `\B@` in the above regex matches the `@` before `Alice` and the another separate `@` symbol. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice versa*). So the following `\b` makes the pattern to match only the first because the first `@` itself followed by a word character ie, `A`.

Comment: Great answer.  I upvoted it per the **About-face** in my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))@(?!\s)
```

Try this.This will replace `@` only from the start of word.if `@` is in the middle of word like `as@sas` it will save it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/44

```
re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<=\s))@(?!\s)','',s)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Initial Answer

Try the following regex:

```
@(?! )
```

Here are a couple examples of how it performs:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?! )', '', '@Alice @ home')
Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?! )', '', 'Whatever @Alice @ home')
Whatever Alice @ home
```

You can also test it with [a related regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/c3zba6).

Key points:

- `@` – *the at-sign*
- `(?! )` – a negative lookahead that matches anything but a space (i.e. *not followed by a space*)

Personally I find the zero-width word-boundary assertions (`\b` and `\B`) a bit distracting and prefer to use [zero-width lookarounds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for this sort of thing, but TMTOWTDI.

### About-face

I thought about this more (as usual), and what I found is admittedly a compelling case for the zero-width word-boundary assertions' simplicity and start- and end-of-string matching.

Consider a fuller set of conceivable tweets:

```
@Alice @ home
Whatever @Alice @ home
What're you lookin' @
What're you lookin' @?
```

It turns out that to get these right requires a much more complicated negative lookahead, turning my initial regex into:

```
@(?![ \W]|$)
```

As before, here are examples of how it performs:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?![ \W]|$)', '', '@Alice @ home')
Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?![ \W]|$)', '', 'Whatever @Alice @ home')
Whatever Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?![ \W]|$)', '', "What're you lookin' @")
What're you lookin' @
>>> print re.sub(r'@(?![ \W]|$)', '', "What're you lookin' @?")
What're you lookin' @?
```

And as before, you can also test it with [a related regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/j3cdq).

*But* a word-boundary pattern like Avinash Raj employed gets this fuller set of conceivable tweets right...with much less fanfare:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', '', '@Alice @ home')
Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', '', 'Whatever @Alice @ home')
Whatever Alice @ home
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', '', "What're you lookin' @")
What're you lookin' @
>>> print re.sub(r'\B@\b', '', "What're you lookin' @?")
What're you lookin' @?
```

Test it out with [another related regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/k2rjr6) if you like too.

Bottom line, this has been a cool learning experience for me to question what I tend to prefer using, and I hope you find it the same: onward on our word-boundary-assertion adventures! :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way working for me:

```
>>> s = '@Alice @ home'
>>> re.sub('\s@\s', ' at ', s).replace('@', '')
'Alice at home'
```